# ¿Cómo abrir un pdf desde Xamarin Android?

Tags: pdf, xamarin.android

Tengo un método que recibe un arreglo de Bytes, el cual contiene un pdf, mi problema es que no se como abrir el pdf, o como indicarle que lo abra con una app ya instalada en el móvil, en la línea dónde está el siguiente código:

```
intent.SetDataAndType(global::Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(localImage), "application/pdf");
```

Cómo le indico que aplicación abrirá el pdf? quiero que me muestre las app's que sean capaces de abrir el pdf

```
public void OpenPdf()
            {
                try
                {
                    byte[] imageBytes = pdf;
                    string documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                    string localFilename = "pdfRecibo.pdf";
                    string localPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(documentsPath, localFilename);
                    File.WriteAllBytes(localPath, imageBytes); // writes to local storage   
                    var localImage = new Java.IO.File(localPath);
                    if (localImage.Exists())
                    {
                        global::Android.Net.Uri uri = global::Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(localImage);
                        var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, uri);
                        //intent.SetType ("application/pdf");
                        intent.SetDataAndType(global::Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(localImage), "application/pdf");
                        this.StartActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "error: " + ex.Message, ToastLength.Short).Show();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya pude abrir el pdf, sólo mando cómo parámetro el arreglo de bytes[] y el nombre del archivo, sobre cómo lo llamaré

```
        public async Task<string> SaveFiles(string filename, byte[] bytes)
        {
            var documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            var filePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, filename);
            File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, bytes);
            OpenFile(filePath, filename);
            return filePath;
        }

        public void OpenFile(string filePath, string filename)
        {

            var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

            //Copy the private file's data to the EXTERNAL PUBLIC location
            string externalStorageState = global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageState;
            string application = "";

            string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filePath);

            switch (extension.ToLower())
            {
                case ".doc":
                case ".docx":
                    application = "application/msword";
                    break;
                case ".pdf":
                    application = "application/pdf";
                    break;
                case ".xls":
                case ".xlsx":
                    application = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                    break;
                case ".jpg":
                case ".jpeg":
                case ".png":
                    application = "image/jpeg";
                    break;
                default:
                    application = "*/*";
                    break;
            }
            var externalPath = global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path + "/" + filename + extension;
            File.WriteAllBytes(externalPath, bytes);

            Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(externalPath);
            file.SetReadable(true);
            //Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("file://" + filePath);
            Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
            intent.SetDataAndType(uri, application);
            intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearWhenTaskReset | ActivityFlags.NewTask);

            try
            {
                this.StartActivity(intent);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "No hay aplicaciones instaladas para abrir PDF's", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
        }
```

Comment: oye el metodo StartActivity me dice que no existe porque se debe eso?